# Assign variable in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have assigned two array to smarty : `profiles` and `selected_id` . `profiles` array contains the array of all profiles and the `selected_id` array contains ids of the profiles to be displayed .So I am displaying the all profiles like this :

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="profiles[]">
        {foreach name = feach item = k from = $profiles}
            <option value="{$k->bz_pro_id}">{$k->bz_pro_first_name} {$k->bz_pro_last_name}</option>
        {/foreach}
      </select>
```

Now I want to default select the ids that are already selected by admin . That means if I want to add `selected = "selected"` in the `option` of `select` . For that I write :

```
{foreach name = feach item = k from = $profiles}
        {foreach name = feach2 item = k2 from = $selected_id}
                {if $k->bz_pro_id == $k2->bz_pro_id}
                        selected = "selected"
                {/if}
        {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

So can I assign the `select = "selected"` to a variable so that I can use it in the `option` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this, and it works. Assuming your arrays look something like this:

```
$profiles[] = array ( 'bz_pro_id' => '1', 'bz_pro_first_name' => 'test1', 'bz_pro_last_name' => 'test2');
$profiles[] = array ( 'bz_pro_id' => '2', 'bz_pro_first_name' => 'test3', 'bz_pro_last_name' => 'test4');
$selected_id = array('1');
```

The syntax you're using to access variables and array members isn't correct. This is the working solution:

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="profiles[]">
    {foreach name=feach item=k from=$profiles}
        <option value="{$k.bz_pro_id}" 
           {if in_array($k.bz_pro_id, $selected_id)}selected{/if}>
            {$k.bz_pro_first_name} {$k.bz_pro_last_name}
        </option>
    {/foreach}
  </select>
```

Comment: I tried this a/c to ur suggestion `{foreach name = feach9 item = k9 from = $profiles}
  {if in_array($k9->bz_pro_id,$selected_id)}Hiiii{/if}
{/foreach}` . But it does not show anything !

Comment: I still did not get anything, `print_r($profiles)` shows `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [bz_pro_first_name] => Al Zahir [bz_pro_last_name] => Hussain [bz_pro_id] => 9 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [bz_pro_first_name] => Christian [bz_pro_last_name] => John [bz_pro_id] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [bz_pro_first_name] => Justin [bz_pro_last_name] => Law [bz_pro_id] => 1 ) )` and `print_r($selected_id)` shows `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [bz_pro_id] => 9 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [bz_pro_id] => 2 ) )`

Comment: Ok, then I made the wrong assumption about the access of the array members. Replace $k. with $k-> to fix it. As for the $selected_id, it will be simpeler if $selected_id is an array of only the values of the selected bz_pro_id values, instead of an array of stdClasses. Like this: $selected_id = array(9, 2);

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code.

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="profiles[]">
        {foreach name = feach item = k from = $profiles}
            <option value="{$k->bz_pro_id}" {if $k->bz_pro_id|in_array($selected_id)}selected = "selected"{/if}  >{$k->bz_pro_first_name} {$k->bz_pro_last_name}</option>
        {/foreach}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="name" value="Bob"}
```

Reference: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl